# Displaying a message at the top of the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, message

I want to display a message to the user in the same way as the following message "Invalid password" but I do not know what this kind of messages are called, and how they can be implemented.

[image]

Comment: Hi!
You can implement this by yourself (creating and UIView with the content you want to display and presenting it with an animation by adding it as a subview to the ViewController you want) or you can check this list of open source libraries -> https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#alert--action-sheet
and see if one of these can help you.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for such an amazing help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not standard messages, they are just `UIView`s (with a slight transparancy) that are located on top of the view stack and being hidden and displayed due to some events.

Just search for something like "overlay views" in a search engine of your choice.
I quickly found the following (without knowing them):

https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages

http://zappdesigntemplates.com/create-your-own-overlay-view-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Please use below library for the same.which is very appropriate and accurate and very easy to implement.

https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages

I think SwiftMessages is easily fulfill your requirements.